# My bootstrap navbar list is vertical not horizontal

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, navbar

I've been trying to work this out for hours. I've searched but none of the solutions I've found online have helped. So I want to know why my navbar list isn't going vertical and also why the "logout" and "My Posts" don't drop down when "Author" is selected like it should. Here is the html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">
      Bella<span class="light">blog</span>
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up pull-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
      &#9776;
    </button>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-sm-right hidden-xs-down">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'Blog', root_path, class: "nav-link #{yield(:blog_active)}" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'About', about_path, class: "nav-link #{yield(:about_active)}" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'Contact', contact_path, class: "nav-link #{yield(:contact_active)}" %>
      </li>
      <% if author_signed_in? %>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Author
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <li>
            <%= link_to 'My Posts', authors_posts_path, class: "dropdown-item #{yield(:author)}" %>
          </li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_author_session_path, method: :delete, class: "dropdown-item" %>
        </div>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the scss:

```
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
  .navbar-brand {
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: $accent-color;
    .light {
      font-weight: 300;
      color: white;
    }
  }
  .navbar-expand-* {
    outline: none;
  }
  .nav-link {
    color: $light-primary-color !important;
    &.active {
      color: $text-primary-color !important;
    }
  }
}

.collapse-bg {
  padding: 0 !important;
  .card {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
  }
}


.collapse-bg .card .list-group-item {
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border-color: black;
  a {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color: #bdc3c7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    &:active {
      color: white;
      border-bottom: none;
    }
  }
}
```

It's not just my code that's playing up. I also used that navbar off this example given https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp
and still no dropdown

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should check the bootstrap css and js imports in your html file

please [refer : Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) !

Dropdowns,Tooltips and Popovers for displaying and positioning (requires Popper.js)

> Please make sure you have imported all **(bootstrap.min.css, jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js, popper.min.js, bootstrap.min.js)** bootstrap file correctly.

And for vertical navbar list try using bootstrap **sidenav** instead of navbar

[sidenav example](https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/sidenav/)

I Hope this is the answer you are looking for.. :)